# What's wrong with this C# login form logic?

Tags: c#, sql-server, logic

I'm having an issue with building a c# login system, first i have a database table that has the following columns:-

```
UserName(nvarchar(255)), 
Password(nvarchar(255)),
Admin(nvarchar(255))
```

Here are the info stored in the table:-

```
admin, 123, true
user, 123, false
```

I have made a c# method called (AuthenticateUsers) to handle the login stored procedure in SQL Server and it is working properly.

Here it is :-

```
public static DataTable AuthenticateUsers()
        {
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            string SqlConnStr = globals.ServerConnStr;
            SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnStr);
            try
            {
                SqlConn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AuthenticateUsers", SqlConn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                Adpt.Fill(DT);
                SqlConn.Close();

            }
            finally
            {
                SqlConn.Close();
            }
            return DT;
        }
```

Here is the Stored Procedure:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuthenticateUsers]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM Login
END
```

Here is the login Windows form code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GlobalClasses.Data.AuthenticateUsers();
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
    try
    {
        if (dr["UserName"].ToString() == UsernameTxtBox.Text 
         && dr["Password"].ToString() == PasswordTxtBox.Text 
         && dr["Admin"].ToString() == "true")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello Admin");
        }
        else if (dr["UserName"].ToString() == UsernameTxtBox.Text 
              && dr["Password"].ToString() == PasswordTxtBox.Text 
              && dr["Admin"].ToString() == "false")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello Normal User");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Get Away");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the first and last `if` statement are working properly however, the second `if` statement is not working at all, i made a `breakpoint` and it just jumped from `if statement 2` to the message box of `if statement 3`.

Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: While you are at it with the debugger, could you tell us what is the content of the UserName, Password and Admin row's columns?

Comment: Print debug Dt value please

Comment: @Steve yes, the value for Username  is "user", and Password is "123" but for Admin it is not showing me a value, instead it's "Class.System.String"

Comment: As a side note, I am not sure because I can't see what happens in your AuthenticateUsers method but your code seems to store passwords in clear text in the database. This is a really bad practice from a security standpoint

Comment: So the problem is not here, but in your AuthenticateUsers and sub methods that fail to recognize correctly the Admin column type

Comment: @Steve its just a test my friend, my main point now is to get the right logic

Comment: Without the code of AuthenticateUsers I can only suggest that a boolean value should be stored as a boolean (BIT datatype) in your database and not as a string. As is the code should work, but clearly something broken is inside the AuthenticateUsers.

Comment: @Steve thanks for your effort, i have updated the question and posted the codes of the AuthenticateUsers and the Stored Procedure, i'm gonna try to make the value boolean as you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offence, but the real answer is **Everything**.

- You use an nvarchar(255) column for everything in your table.
  User names are rarely longer then 15 characters and passwords are usually between 4 and 6 characters. you can safely use nvarchar(20) for user name and password, and a Bit column for `Admin`.
- Your column names are bad. UserName, Password and Admin are reserved words in most databases. My advice is to use the table name as a prefix for column names: `Login_UserName`, `Login_Password`, `Login_Admin`.
- You are saving passwords in the database as plain text. Passwords should only ever be saved encrypted.
- You are using a stored procedure to select All data from the table back to your c# code. what you should do is pass the user's input as parameters to the stored procedure and return only the data you need back to your c# program.

A correct stored procedure would look more like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuthenticateUsers]
(
    @UserName nvarchar(255),
    @Password nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT Admin 
FROM Login
WHERE UserName = @UserName
AND Password = @Password

END
```

(this is consistent with your current table)

Comment: thanks a lot it now works but unfortunately, the third `if statement` doesn't work, it's either admin or user but if the username and password are wrong nothing happens.. thank you once more :)

Comment: If the users enters the wrong user name or password, the stored procedure I wrote will return an empty result set. I don't know what your updated code looks like now, so it's hard for me to tell you what you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

i think that the second "if" is not gets "true" in all 3 conditions.

i suggest you to watch the boolean answer of each condition.

you can do it also by set 3 boolean variables, in the beginning , and see what boolean answer you get from each condition.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all rows but only checking first row of your query

```
dt.Rows[0]
```

and since your first row is :

```
admin, 123, true
```

this condition:

`dr["Admin"].ToString() == "false"`

is always false. If you want to authenticate user you should get form you DB only those users who are admins:

```
SELECT * FROM Login where Admin = true
```

Assuiming there is only one admin in database (otherwise you should change your logic and either iterate through rows or use regular query instead of stored procedure)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GlobalClasses.Data.AuthenticateUsers();
    try
    {
        for(var i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++){
            var dr = dt.Rows[i]; 
            if (dr["UserName"].ToString() == UsernameTxtBox.Text 
            && dr["Password"].ToString() == PasswordTxtBox.Text ){
                if (dr["Admin"].ToString() == "true"){
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello Admin");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello Normal User");
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Get Away");
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: how to check all columns in the `dt.Rows[0]`

Comment: just iterate : `for(var i=0; i < dt.Rows.length; i++){
 var dr = dt.Rows[i];
 //put your try/if's here
}`

Comment: dt.Rows.Length is not valid my friend :)